# How to reconnect to a nodemon session from another terminal

Tags: node.js, typescript, terminal, centos7, nodemon

so I have a nodeJS server that's coded in TypeScript and uses nodemon to live update as I develop the code

to run the server, I run `npm start` and my start script in package.json is `concurrently \"tsc && tsc -w\" nodemon`

Now my question:

How can I connect to that terminal session so I can get the server console logs from a different terminal?

Case example:

I have my server running on an SSH server, however I have colleagues that would like to monitor the output of the server, how can they see the same terminal output from the one I have where I ran `npm start` on? And It's necessary to be the same command, i don't want to stir up another nodeJS server

EDIT: OS being used is CentOS 7

Answer (score 0):

You can save and later recconect to terminal session using [screen](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Screen)

> Screen is a terminal multiplexer, which allows a user to access
>   multiple separate terminal sessions inside a single terminal window or
>   remote terminal session (such as when using SSH).

Comment: Yes, imply yum install screen